# Solana: How to fix an invalid public key problem?

Tags: javascript, swap, solana, solana-web3js

I need your help because I've been stuck on this for several days.

I'm trying to do a super simple swap on Solana. Between Sol and USDC on devnet with Raydium.

```
const { Connection, Keypair, PublicKey } = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { Liquidity, TokenAmount, Token, Percent } = require('@raydium-io/raydium-sdk');

const devnetConnection = new Connection('https://api.devnet.solana.com');
const privateKey = []; // secretKey
const wallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(privateKey));

const ADDRESSFROM = 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112';
const ADDRESSTO = 'EP2ib6dYdEeqD8MfE2ezHCxX3kP3K2eLKkirfPm5eyMx';
const OWNER = '675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8';

async function main() {
  const poolKeys = {
    id: new PublicKey(OWNER),
  };

  const TOKENFROM = new Token(devnetConnection, new PublicKey(ADDRESSFROM), 9, wallet.publicKey);
  const TOKENTO = new Token(devnetConnection, new PublicKey(ADDRESSTO), 6, wallet.publicKey);  

  const rawAmountIn = 1;
  const amountIn = new TokenAmount(TOKENFROM, rawAmountIn * 10**TOKENFROM.decimals, false);

  const slippage = new Percent(50, 10000);
  const poolInfo = await Liquidity.fetchInfo(devnetConnection, poolKeys);
  const { minAmountOut } = Liquidity.computeAmountOut(poolInfo, amountIn, TOKENTO, slippage);

  const { transaction, signers } = await Liquidity.makeSwapTransaction({
    connection: devnetConnection,
    poolKeys,
    userKeys: {
      owner: wallet.publicKey,
    },
    amountIn,
    amountOut: minAmountOut,
    fixedSide: 'in',
  });

  const signature = await devnetConnection.sendTransaction(transaction, [wallet, ...signers]);
  console.log(`Transaction hash: ${signature}`);

  await devnetConnection.confirmTransaction(signature);
  console.log(`Transaction confirmed: ${signature}`);
}

main().catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

I can't resolve this public key issue and make a transaction.

```
reason: 'invalid public key',
code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
argument: 'publicKey',
```

Answer (score 0):

The USDC address on devnet is different than mainnet.

You're using the mainnet address of `EP2ib6dYdEeqD8MfE2ezHCxX3kP3K2eLKkirfPm5eyMx`, but if you look at that account on devnet, you'll see that it doesn't exist https://explorer.solana.com/address/EP2ib6dYdEeqD8MfE2ezHCxX3kP3K2eLKkirfPm5eyMx?cluster=devnet

This is the official devnet USDC address: https://explorer.solana.com/address/4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU?cluster=devnet